# Why can't I print that value?

Tags: c

I am very new to C programming.

I was going through some practicing and I was creating a program that will count the number of lines of text written.

I used the getchar() function.

I don't know why I can't print that value.

Also, I tried to print the same value inside the loop and it did print.  But that outputs a lot of values.

So, I wanted to print the last value of the linecount.

[Here is my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY0mh.png)
[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPLR.png)

Why doesn't printf print the value outside that while loop??

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post pictures of text: post the text using copy-paste. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please, never post images of your code and outputs. Always include them in your question.

Comment: I will make sure that I don't post images!!!
I'm really sorry!!!

Comment: I am actually learning from the book "The C programming language" 2nd edition. 
There is a program which counts the number of lines of input given using getchar(). 
But the same program I'm running on my computer isn't behaving the same way...
This is what I wanted to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that your program is not getting out of the while loop.
Did you try entering

```
Ctrl+z
```

followed by an enter.
??

Comment: The image would appear to be Linux, which uses Ctrl-D. Ctrl-Z is for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the input system that the input is ending. If not you won't get out the loop. For that, in interactive mode you need to input a special character. *nix systems uses -D.